# PyQt5 Can i remove Progress from Statusbar when Checkbox is uncheckd?

Tags: python, editor, pyqt5, statusbar, progress

So i'am new to PyQt5 and i'am trying to remove progress from the status bar when the Checkbox is unchecked. Now, when i hit the Checkbox and check it, the status bar set the progress 1 step forward.But when i unchecked the status bar, the progress is still set on the steps from forward. 
here is my code to this.

```
def deactivate_header(self, state):
    if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
        self.ui.headerText.setDisabled(True)
        self.ui.fBar.setValue(25)
    else:
        self.ui.headerText.setDisabled(False)
        self.ui.fBar.setValue(-25)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the progress bar's `setValue` method sets the absolute value, it doesn't adjust the value from where it is.  To move the progress bar's value back by 25 when the checkbox is unchecked try:

```
self.ui.fBar.setValue(self.ui.fBar.value() - 25)
```